# Parts Of HTML / CSS Code not showing up on page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a second background/box but it isn't showing up on my page. The specific code:

The MAIN-PAGE Class HTML and CSS

```
 <div class="MAIN-PAGE"></div>



.MAIN-PAGE {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: red;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working but your looking for "background-color: red;"

Answer (score 3):

You need to append the prefix "background-" to your property color. Full Example:

```css
.MAIN-PAGE {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="MAIN-PAGE"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `color` style for the color of the text inside the container and the `background-color` style for the background color.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Test</title>
    
    <style>
    .MAIN-PAGE {
      position: fixed;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    
    /* text color */
      color: red;
    
    /* background color */
      background-color: black;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body> 
<div class="MAIN-PAGE">test</div>
</body>
</html>
```